# Terraform Upgrade 0.14 to 1.1.9 showing addition in resource without change in configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform was working on version 0.14.11 since long. That is been upgraded to v1.1.9 without changing any configuration. Yet in terraform plan it is showing that certain argument will be added.

For example in aws_dbinstance, no configuration is changed and also argument like `character_set_name`, `domain`  etc.(Marked as Bold) are not defined in resource yet in plan those values are getting showed as addition.

```
~ resource "aws_db_instance" "test" {
    **+ character_set_name                    = ""
    + domain                                = ""
    + domain_iam_role_name                  = ""**
      id                                    = "test"
    **+ identifier_prefix                     = ""**
      name                                  = "test"
    **+ nchar_character_set_name              = ""**
    # Warning: this attribute value will be marked as sensitive and will not
    # display in UI output after applying this change. The value is unchanged.
    ~ password                              = (sensitive value)
    **+ performance_insights_kms_key_id       = ""
    + replica_mode                          = ""
    + replicate_source_db                   = ""**
      tags                                  = {
      "Name"        = "test"
      "environment" = "test"
      "product"     = "test"
      }
   **+ timezone                              = ""**
  }
```

Is there any clue on this behavior ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that's just being explicit about defaults values now.

Comment: @jordanm : Ironically these values are blank and optional.

So do you mean whichever value are getting adjusted by terraform will explicitly shown in plan even if it is empty which was not shown in earlier version ?

Comment: I am saying that AWS transparently set these to blank/empty on the AWS side. Previously TF didn't account for this which would sometimes result in an issue where TF would say there are changes when they are not. Newer versions add these default so you only get this drift once.

Comment: Additionally this appears more like a provider update than a TF update.

Comment: As @MattSchuchard points, did you update `aws` provider? Or it's the same version as in `0.14.11`?